# Iphone starts lagging and not responding while debugging via Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I've been trying to test my app on IPhone but the phone freezes time to time and stop responding for a while and so .. when its connected to Mac 
(Mac is Installed on VMWare and there has been nothing wrong with it till now even the emulator)
any Idea on what may cause the problem ?

Comment: Your question is far too broad and vague to get truly useful answers.  If the bad behavior is a recent change, can you comment some of your new code out and see if behavior gets better?  Doing that might help you to isolate what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest restarting the simulator and Xcode

first quit Xcode then make sure the active window is the simulator next what you want to do is look up at the task bar (gray bar at the top of the screen) click on hardware and then scroll down to reboot and click that, the simulator will now restart when the simulator finishes restarting navigate over to simulator and click on "reset all content and settings"

if that does not fix the problem try using another simulated device in my experience some work better then others (try the iPhone SE or the iPhone 5s they have worked better for me)

Comment: if that doesn't work it may be a problem with VMWare I would recommend restarting the program and seeing if that helps

Comment: as I said its fine on simulators but when an actual iPhone is  connected the phone is not responsive and starts to freeze time to time , and I have to mention that when I connect it starts no matter if xcode is running an App on it or even if xcode open itself

Comment: I do apologize your question isn't very clear try rebooting your device and the VMWare Mac then try it but if that doesn't work it could be another software issue because your PC is having to translate the connection so that the VMWare Mac can detect it which is probably where the problem is. most likely you are not the only one with this problem so I would recommend doing some research about the issue

Comment: it could also be a hardware issue